# Run macro and hyperlink in one mouse click

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need a button in a PowerPoint slide that when I click it, it will, 1) run a macro and 2) hyperlink to another slide within the same presentation.

I can only see a way to do one or the other, not both at the same time.

My macro code is:

```
Sub question1_real()
Dim oSh As Shape
   Dim oSl As Slide
   Dim lScore As Long

   ' By doing it this way it's easy to change to a different slide if you
   ' need to later for some reason:
   Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(18)

   ' Change this if your shape is named something else:
   Set oSh = oSl.Shapes("TextBox 2")

   With oSh
      ' Make sure it's not blank to start with:
      If Len(.TextFrame.TextRange.Text) = 0 Then
          .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "1"
      End If
      lScore = CLng(.TextFrame.TextRange.Text)
      lScore = lScore + 1
      .TextFrame.TextRange.Text = CStr(lScore)
   End With
End Sub
```

My VBA skills are zero. The above code is borrowed from someone. I used the Insert Action option in PowerPoint to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've given a shape a Run Macro action setting and chosen the subroutine you've posted above, you can add this function to the VBA project:

Sub JumpTo(lSlideIndex As Long)
    SlideShowWindows(1).View.GoToSlide (lSlideIndex)
End Sub

Then wherever you want to jump to another slide, call it like so:

```
Call JumpTo(42) ' or whatever slide you want to jump to
```

or just

```
JumpTo 42
```

It's more convenient to have this in a Function if you need to use it more than once in the presentation. If it's strictly a one-shot, you can just paste this into your existing code:

```
SlideShowWindows(1).View.GoToSlide (42)
```